# UIGestureRecognizer override the collectionViewCell in iOS 15, Xcode 13.0

Tags: swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios15

[image]

**B**: Transparent View with alpha 0.1 and attached Gesture recognizer, that will dismiss the view

`bView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismisClicked(_:))))`

**C**: UIView

**D**: Collection View Cells

**iOS 14** work normal

**iOS 15** {B}'s TabGesture override collection view touches and scroll

Comment: What is your question?  ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: i can't interact with collectionView. If i remove the {B}'s TabGesture, i cant interact with collectionView, but i need someway to dismiss the view when touching outside the collectionView